Referencing an existing resource which is present in a bicep module
I am new to bicep so I am might be missing something simple here. I have a container registry resource in subscription 'sub1' and resource group 'rg1'. I created a bicep module which looks like below:
@description('Name of the registry.')
param regName string

targetScope = 'subscription'

resource myreg 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-01-01' existing = {
  name: regName
  scope: resourceGroup('reg1')
}

output acrResource resource = myreg (NOTE: this is asking me to enable experimental features...which I want to avoid)
output acrId string = myreg.id
output acrName string = myreg.name

I am using this bicep template like below:
module myreg 'myreg.bicep'= {
  name: 'myreg'
  params: {
    regName: 'foo'
  }
  scope: subscription('sub1')
}


resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' {
  name: 'guid-here'
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: acrPullRoleDefinitionId
    principalId: 'principa-id-here'
  }
  scope: myreg.outputs.acrResource (this one does not work as I need to enable experimental feature to make the module file error go away)
}

Questions:
How is an existing resource from different sub and resource group referenced in general? I could not find examples online too. This should be straight forward but I am stuck here. Any ideas on how I can get unblocked?
Thanks for your help.

I do not think you can split roleAssignment and registries, even bicep support resource type output.

You can reference a resource from a different sub/rg like that (see documentation)
resource myreg 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-01-01' existing = {
  name: regName
  scope: resourceGroup('sub1', 'reg1')
}

For role assignment, because the scope is the container registry, your module needs to be scoped to this specific resource.
container-registry-role-assignment.bicep:
param containerRegistryName string
param principalId string
param roleId string

// Get a reference to the existing container registry
resource containerRegistry 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-11-01-preview' existing = {
  name: containerRegistryName
}

// Create the role assignment
resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(containerRegistry.id, roleId, principalId)
  scope: containerRegistry
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: principalId
  }
}

Then from the parent module, you can invoke it like that:
@description('Name of the registry.')
param regName string

targetScope = 'subscription'

module containerRegistryRbac 'container-registry-role-assignment.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup('sub1', 'reg1') // scope of the sub-deployment
  name: 'name-of-the-deployment'
  params: {
    containerRegistryName: regName
    principalId: 'principa-id-here'
    roleId: '7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d' // AcrPull
  }
}


Thank you very much for your prompt response. This helped me in fixing the issue!
